# I keep getting null error in JDBC. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, null

I'm writing a program where the user has to sign in. I've reviewed my code again and again but I keep getting "null" as the error. This is not only the case for the sign in part of the program, but also for the part where the user can create an account. Basically, wherever I've implemented JDBC, a "null" error pops up. How do I fix this?

```
String user_name_check = user_name.getText().trim();
char[] pass = password_enter.getPassword();
String password_check = Arrays.toString(pass);
String query = "SELECT * FROM USER_INFO WHERE USERNAME = '" + user_name_check + "';";
try{
    rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()){
        //changing the panel (start)
        if(password_check.equals(rs.getString("PASS"))){
            MAIN.removeAll();
            MAIN.add(news_feed);
            MAIN.repaint();
            MAIN.revalidate();
            //changing the panel (end)
            //giving values to class level field variables (start)
            username = user_name_check;
            firstname = rs.getString("FIRST_NAME");
            lastname = rs.getString("LAST_NAME");
            dob = rs.getString("DOB");
            gender = rs.getString("GENDER");
            bio = rs.getString("BIO");
            home_user_name.setText(username);
            set_dp(home_user_dp, username);
        }
    }
    else sign_in_message.setVisible(true);
}

catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " @jButton2ActionPerformed SIGN IN");
}
```

The error : null @jButton2ActionPerformed SIGN IN

**EDIT**

Here's the JDBC connection method :

```
     public void JDBC_Connect(){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/socialnetwork", "root", "mukundrox");
        st = con.createStatement();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " @JDBC_connect");
    }
}
```

Comment: show us `e.toString()`

Comment: What line of code is having the problem?

Comment: Print the stack trace (instead of the just `e.getMessage()` and SIGN IN).

Comment: can you show us how you instantiated the rs object ?

Comment: `e.printStackTrace()` should be used within the `catch` block and show us the result

Comment: You're doing this wrong anyway. You should use SQL of the form `SELECT * FROM USER_INFO WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASS = ?` and let the database do the comparing. And use a `PreparedStatement`. Then if `rs.next()` is true, there is such a user with that password, otherwise there isn't. You haven't needed the `Class.forName()` line since 2007.